# Saving changes made when editing with /wysihtml5

Tags: html, save, editing

I am looking for some guidance on how to save editing done using /wysihtml5.

I have googled using several different combinations of search terms but virtually all the hits I get are github.  I have looked through the examples on that site but I can't find anything that explains how the changes can be saved once a user edits a page.

I do have some php and sql knowledge but would like some pointers to exactly what I need to do to get changes made using /wysihtml5 saved.   The other instructions appear very comprehensive so I wonder why this aspect seems to be missing.

Can anyone help please?

Many thanks

Brenda

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki/Getting-Started), if you simply submit your form the editor's content will be available as a posted value.

Comment: When I look at the examples provided in github there is no submit button, only a reset button.  If you are looking at another source of information I would be really grateful for a link to it.

Answer (score 4):

According to the editor's [Getting Started](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki/Getting-Started) page, it works by replacing a regular `<textarea>` with the rich editor:

> wysihtml5 takes a textarea and transforms it into a rich text editor.
>   The textarea acts as a fallback for unsupported browsers (eg. IE < 8).
>   Make sure the textarea element has an id, so we can later access it
>   easily from javascript. The resulting rich text editor will much
>   behave and look like the textarea since behavior (placeholder,
>   autofocus, …) and css styles will be copied over.
>
> **Please note**: The textarea will always hold the editor’s generated
>   markup. Therefore wysihtml5 integrates smoothly with forms.

So, the editor's content will always be available as the value of the textarea, and you can use it as you would with a regular form element (submit the form, or get the contents with JavaScript and send it to PHP using Ajax).

For example, consider you apply the editor to the following:

```
<form action="somescript.php" method="POST">
    <textarea id="wysihtml5-textarea" name="wysihtml5-textarea"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

If you submit the form by clicking the button, your php script will receive the contents on `$_POST["wysihtml5-textarea"]` (change the *name* of the textarea to set the desired key on `$_POST`).

If you want to get the value using JavaScript, select the `<textarea>` by ID, then access the element's value:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("wysihtml5-textarea");
alert(textarea.value);
```

Then you can pass that value to PHP using Ajax if you want. The PHP/SQL implementation for actually saving the data is up to you, the editor's code just takes care of providing a rich text editor, and formatting features.

Note: I never used that editor, so my answer might be not be 100% accurate.